# Encode VP8 frames in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, frame, encode, vp8

How I can encode CMSampleBuffer I get from the camera from my iPhone to VP8 frames to send them to a UDP port in WebSocket?
There is no library in Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: Any sample code to start from?